# How can I take a .txt file full of a table of values and header and convert it to a numpy 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I do the following with the attached .txt file using python? :
Create a function fnamedata(filename) to read in the data provided in .txt file.
Then take the data from the text file and return the data in a 2-dimensional array.
This array needs to be made using numpy, and must be accessible, to allow other functions to lookup values.

The result should be an array that can be accessed to retrieve certain values.
Thanks for the help

.txt file:

```
31  1.04    1.04    1.04    1.96    1.04    1.98        
38  1.04    1.85    1.86    1.87    1.88    1.89    
3   1.04    1.76    1.04    1.78    1.79    1.80    
36  1.04    1.67    1.68    1.69    1.70    1.71    
3   1.04    1.58    1.59    1.60    1.61    1.62    
3   1.04    1.49    1.50    1.51    1.52    1.53        
3   1.09    1.40    1.41    1.42    1.43    1.44    
32  1.00    1.31    1.32    1.33    1.34    1.35    
3   1.01    1.22    1.23    1.24    1.25    1.26    
29  1.03    1.04    1.05    1.04    1.07    1.04
```

Comment: Could you share the code for your `readData(filename: str):ndarray`?

Comment: The readData(filename: str):ndarray, is just a sample name for the function. def readData(filename) . I am trying to find a way to create a function to convert that .txt file into a 2-d array in python that can be used by numpy to find specific values.

Comment: Also, take a look into [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). It might be overkill, but you could use it to read your `.txt` (from what I understood, the values are separeted by a common value) and then use `pd.DataFrame.values` to get your `np.array`

Comment: Do you need x and y axis names in your array? or just the data?

Comment: @JoonyoungPark yes, i need the x/y axis name(including the"temp" header, which is what I cant understand to do.

Comment: Oh, you didn't write the function? Have you tried to write it? Is this an asignment? Take a look into [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @FelipeWhitaker I've tried, this is what i have: def getData(fname):
    import numpy as np
    lst=[]
    f = open(fname, "r")
    for x in f:
        lst.append(int(x))
    f.close()
    column = 1
    row = 0
    while column*row !=len(lst):
        column +=1
        row +=1
    arr = np.array(lst)
    arr = arr.reshape(row,column)
    return arr

Comment: What is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# read file
f = open('file.txt', 'r+')
data_as_list = f.read()
f.close()

# preprocess data
columns = f.pop(0).split()
# correct for Temp C
starts = columns.pop(0)
columns[0] = f'{starts} {columns[0]}'

# convert the data to floats and fill out missing data with None
def convert(s: str):
    data = list(map(float, s.split()))
    return data + [None, ] * (len(columns) - len(data)) # fill put the 
data_as_list = list(map(convert, data_as_list))

# create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data_as_list, columns = columns)

# access the entry
print(df.loc[1, '0.10'])

P.S. Just noted that you want to wrap it in a function. What should be the arguments?
```

Comment: its fine if it isnt in a function, I can add it in later. I just need to understand the basics of how to make the array

Comment: syntax error:File "main.py", line 12                                                                                                                                                          
    columns[0] = f"{starts} {columns[0]} "

Comment: Is your data accurate with respect to spaces stated in the question? Can you please post here the first line?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have figured out a way to work around the issue and don't need the first line.